# Is Bogoliubov transformation the only canonical transformation possible for QFT in curved spacetime?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime

As in the title, is Bogoliubov transformation the only canonical transformation (that is, the ones that respect canonical commutation-or-anticommutation relation , or CCR) possible for QFT in a curved spacetime? Or is there any other transformations (from original creation-annihilation basis) that respect CCR?

Comment: There are plenty of allowed transformations of fields in curved spacetime that are not necessarily Bogoliubov transformations. Actually, you need to specify how the algebras of (local) fields transform under the action of spacetime transformations in defining the theory. In the locally covariant formulation, this amounts to the existence of locally covariant quantum fields.